# jQuery datepicker - How to populate due date from chosen date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I am a rails newbie trying to use Datepicker to set up reservations in a rental app. I have it working for the start at date and would like to set a due at for 2 days later. I've gotten stuck and am hoping for some advice on how to proceed...

jQuery

```
$('#rental_start_at').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: (dateText)
```

Comment: Please make a clear question, also paste your code here or use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  What is the due date, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are trying to add 2 days to the selected date from `Datepicker`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
         var dueDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
         dueDate.setDate(dueDate.getDate()+2);
         alert(dueDate);
        }
    });
});
```

I have created [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/gKzgU/), have a look into it.